# Asymptotic development of the black-hole metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, universe, kerr-metric, asymptotics

In the Kruskal-Szekeres extension of the Schwarzschild metric parallel universes appear. In a couple of questions on this site, for instance: [Where does the parallel universe in the Penrose diagram come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/773888/)
it is said that such a geometry requires eternal existence for being "realistic" (well, then it would not be realistic at all).

Why is this requirement necessary? I understand that a black hole geometry created by an extreme violent supernova explosion is affected by its past, but an asymptotic development should finally lead to such a geometry, why in case of a black hole an asymptotic development would really need an infinite amount of time, where in other areas of physics (e.g. particle collisions) such an asymptotic state can be reached within seconds.